# Retrive single data from json object in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js

i am new in nodejs . i tried the below code for retriving json object. but i can't retrive a single data from json object

My code is

```
function getData(){
  var http = require('http');
  var qs = require('querystring');
  var str = '';

  var options = {
        host: '192.168.1.16',
        port: 8080,
        path: '/courseapi/view'
  };

 callback = function(response) {

  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
    console.log(str[0]._id);
  });
}

var req = http.request(options, callback).end();
};
```

i tried this str[0]._id but it return undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
response.on('end', function () {
  str = JSON.parse(str);
  console.log(str);
  console.log(str[0]._id);
});
```